# map vs ?? for storing name and score

Tags: java, list, collections, hashmap

I used hashmap to store data.
The problem is that I just noticed hashmap can't have more than one same key.
What else should I use to store data which the data looks like this:

- Name1  100.0
- Name2  99.8
- Name3  121.5
- ...

Other thing I'm trying to do is to show data of one certain person, when I call that key.
So, is there way to store more than one value related to one key? or should I use other type of storage?

Comment: You can define class. Then define arraylist which stores objects of that class

Comment: Your example doesn't match the description of your problem (all the names are unique?). Having said that I would recommend taking a look at Guava's [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html). It is capable of storing multiple values for the same key.

Answer (score 3):

A hashmap can have duplicate keys if you store the values within another data structure such as a linked list or a tree at each key index. Then you just have to decide how to handle the collisions.

**Edit:**

HashMap

```
["firstKey"] => LinkedList of (3,4,5)
["secondKey"] => null
["thirdKey"] => LinkedList of (3)
```

Answer (score 1):

To extend on Matthew Coxes answer, you could extend the Hashtable Class so that it automatically manages your lists for you and would give you the appearance of having multiple keys.

Comment: This would be my implementation approach. Especially if the OP intends to reuse this data structure in other places.

Answer (score 1):

The Google guava library contain some collection type that allow for more that one element per key. The `Multimap` is the first one that come to mind.

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Guava in general contain a lot of very convenient utilities, I think its worth checking out.

If you can't use an external library, you can simply (Like Matthew Cox said) mix a map and a List with `Map<K, List<V>>`. But that is a bit more inconvenient to work with since you have to initialise a list for every key.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather go with my own datamodel and store that in a list, or map if you want fast access, e.g.

```
public class Player {
    private String name;
    private List<Float> scores;
}
```

The advantages:

- you can easily see, what the structure wants to express
- you can easily extend it (e.g. add aliases for the player, or calculate the avarage scor of player 1)